# Разделить массив на части

Tags: массивы, php, mysql

Есть MySQL запрос:

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT `uvk_id` FROM `users` ORDER BY `uid` ASC LIMIT 900");
 while($d = $db->assoc($q)) {
 $vk_id_list[] = $d['uvk_id'];
}
```

`$vk_id_list` - массив, который содержит 900 значений с id ВКонтакте.

Мне нужно создать **3 массива**, в которых будут **по 300 значений**, например:

> `$array1` будет содержать от 0 до 300
> значений из общего массива `$vk_id_list`
>
> `$array2` будет содержать от 300 до 600
> значений из общего массива `$vk_id_list`
>
> `$array3` будет содержать от 600 до 900
> значений из общего массива `$vk_id_list`

Не подскажете, как реализовать?

Comment: @ReinRaus ♦, забрал array_slice. Превратите свой комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php
Или так:

```
$name= "array1";
$counter=0;
$q = $db->query("SELECT `uvk_id` FROM `users` ORDER BY `uid` ASC LIMIT 900");
while($d = $db->assoc($q)) {
    $$name[] = $d['uvk_id'];
    $counter++;
    if ($counter%300==0) {
        $name= preg_replace("/\\d/", "", $name).($counter\300 +1 );
    };
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!